# Norm and Trace of an element is an integer, then element is an integral?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, trace, minimal-polynomials

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension, and let $\{b_1,b_2,...,b_d\}$ be a basis for $L/K$

My notes define

$O_k:=\mathbb{B}\cap K$, where $\mathbb{B}:=\{\alpha$ is algebraic|min poly of $\alpha$ over $K$ has integer coefficients$\}$

Note:$\mathbb{Z}\subseteq O_k$

$Nm_{L/K}(\alpha)=Nm(m_\alpha)=$ Norm of matrix $m_\alpha$

$Tr_{L/K}(\alpha)=Tr(m_\alpha)=$ Trace of matrix $m_\alpha$

Where the $i^{th}$ column in $m_\alpha$ is the coefficients of $\alpha b_i$ as a linear expression of the basis for $L/K$.

My question is, if $Nm(\alpha),Tr(\alpha)\in \mathbb{Z}$, then does that mean that $\alpha\in O_k$, i.e the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: If the element is quadratic, yes. Otherwise, no, but I cannot think of an example.

Comment: For comparison, consider the case of a matrix: if a matrix with rational entries has integral trace and determinant, is its minimum polynomial automatically integral? Consideration of companion matrices, for example, shows that no, that is not the case. Of course, number are more special, but still.

Comment: yeah I can see why, but then is there a general method for determining if an element is in $O_k$

Comment: apart from computing the characteristic polynomial of the element and showing that it has integer coefficients

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The norm and trace are just two coefficients of the characteristic polynomial.  When $d\geq 3$, there is no reason that their integrality implies integrality of the polynomial.

For example, take: $$\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{17}}}{2}$$ with $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  $\alpha$ has trace $0$ and norm $-1$, but is not integral (it has minimal polynomial $X^4 - \frac{1}{2}X^2 - 1$).